# Why does android init not die?

Tags: linux

As I read from the book Embedded Android (Karim Yaghmour), android init does not die. However, Linux init systems usually die. Why doesn't the android init?

And also, why does android not use / need systemd?

Comment: No, Linux init never die....

Comment: The init process in a unix-type system (which generally has pid 1) never dies. The system needs that process to be there in order to operate properly.

Comment: [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) is a newer take on the concept of the init process. It fulfills the same role, and when we speak of the init process, it doesn't matter what it's called, it matters only what it does, which is start everything else and stay running.

Comment: uhhh.... am not exactly sure what is the OP trying to elicit from this discussion, systemd is more geared towards {desk|lap}tops and servers. Since it would be deemed too "heavy" especially in the arena of mobiles with limited resources...

Answer (score 1):

***Init*** is one of the first processes that is loaded when the Bootloader starts in Unix.
So, technically init is the first process that starts and all other processes are either children or the grandchildren of *init*. 
Now, when a process say *Y*starts execution, it is usually *forked* from its parent process, say *X* when *X* dies(finished executing) the process *Y* now has no parent, and it becomes an *Orphan Process* at this time *init* takes over the ownership of the process and becomes the parent of *Y*.
Like this, there are so many processes running at a given instant in the OS, everything has to be taken care by *init*.
Since Android being a flavor of Linux, and Linux being a derivative of Unix, it is for the same reason that *init* doesn't die,unitll the system shuts down.

Comment: The question is very simple to understand. It asks: "*Linux init systems usually die. Why doesn't the android init?*" You've told what init is and what it does but that *isn't tantamount* to why it cannot die in Android but in other Linux distributions. // Init is the first process in *user-space*, that's what they say and Init is loaded by kernel, not bootloader.